# There is a problem with this website's security certificate

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate, trust

My job has an Outlook Exchange Server so we can access our work email from the web.  However, every time I attempt to log in, I get this message:

"There is a problem with this website's security certificate"

While I can still click "Continue to the website", I'd really rather not have to do this every time.  Is there a way to trust the certificate?

Comment: Click about on that warning message any you can usually find the reason - mismatched names/self signed/expired etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ultrasawblade

> There's really nothing you, on your end, can do about this, unfortunately.

That actually isn't true. Yes it will be that CA is not trusted but all he needs to do is get the root CA certificate from his Exchange admin team and install it into his trusted root store. Then he will no longer get a warning.

See following link on how to install a root CA http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750534.aspx.
here is a bit of info as well about CA's and root certificates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority

Comment: This is true.  I did not think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your job didn't install a certificate on their Exchange server that was signed by a CA that your browser accepts as trusted.

The CA's that Internet Explorer accepts as trusted ("root CA's") out of the box are all third-party companies (Verisign, Thawte, Comodo, and even Microsoft themselves) charge to have this done.  So it's not uncommon for people not to do this for smaller installations.

However, your job can use Windows Server "CA Enrollment Services", issue such a certificate for their domain, and give you instructions on how to import it on your laptop.

There's really nothing you, on your end, can do about this, unfortunately.

Also, another thing: The exchange server within your company network (accessible when you are at work) might have a different domain name than when you are outside of the network.  So, maybe they did get a certificate but only for their internal LAN domain name.  Again, this is something the people who configured the Exchange server would have to handle and there's not a lot you can do from your end.

Comment: Do you know if it is easy for the admins to fix the problem, if it was raised with them?